# .NET 6 SslStream connection fails: "Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream"

Tags: c#, .net, openssl, tls1.2, sslstream

I can successfully connect to a company server using openssl:

```bash
openssl s_client -connect {ip_address}:{tcp_port} -cert client.pem -key client.key -CAfile ca.cer
```

The output shows the negotiated protocol is **TLS 1.2**.

**I'd like to implement this connection in C#**. Here is my current attempt. Note that I provide the client's certificate and private key, but I does not check the server certificate:

```cs
var clientPrivateKey = RSA.Create();
clientPrivateKey.ImportFromPem(File.ReadAllText("client.key"));
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2("client.pem").CopyWithPrivateKey(clientPrivateKey);
var clientCertificates = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);

using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient(ipAddress, tcpPort))
using (var sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream()))
{
  sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
  {
    AllowRenegotiation = true,
    EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13,
    CertificateRevocationCheckMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck,
    ClientCertificates = clientCertificates,
    TargetHost = ipAddress, // ???
    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (_, _, _, _) => true
  });
}
```

Unfortunately `sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient` throws this error:

```bash
Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream. (System.IO.IOException)
```

I have read everything about this problem on MSDN, StackOverflow etc. Some observations:

Although the openssl command line says the protocol is TLS 1.2, I tried other values, and also tried not setting the `EnabledSslProtocols` value, but nothing helped. I also tried changing or omitting `AllowRenegotiation` and `CertificateRevocationCheckMode`, but that did not help either.

The `TargetHost` value cannot be null, but I don't know what it should be. I tried an empty string, the CN from the server's certificate, even the server's IP address, but nothing helped. Interestingly, the openssl command line above says `Can't use SSL_get_servername`, which is suspicious but I don't know what it means exactly.

-- Thank you for your help in advance!

---

**UPDATE:** I checked the traffic using tcpdump. In case of the C# code, there is a SYN/SYN-ACK/ACK, a FIN-ACK/ACK initiated by the server at 5 seconds, and a `Client Hello` from the client at 30 seconds. The client not only waits for 30 seconds, but also tries to use TLS 1.0, whatever settings I use.

Comment: On a socket "received 0 bytes" is indeed the EOF signalling mechanism, and means the remote end has half-closed the connection (they may or may not still be receiving, but they definitely are done transmitting).

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, that's what tcpdump shows (see my UPDATE above). Interestingly, if I set clientCertificates to null, the Client Hello won't wait 30 seconds but I will get "Authentication failed". I think if there is a client cert, something times out before Client Hello -- but what could that be?

Comment: I would say that your client is expecting the server to start out by transmitting a challenge, and the server is waiting for your client to send a request.  Both are waiting, no one talks until the server times out and closes the connection.  Basically, the two ends are not using the same protocol.

Comment: You've already run wireshark to capture the failing exchange from C#.  Now capture the successful connection setup from `openssl`.  Which end sends first?

Comment: @BenVoigt The openssl client sends a TLS 1.2 Client Hello immediately after the SYN/SYN-ACK/ACK. Then the server sent an ACK and the Server Hello, etc.

Comment: And what OS are you running on?  Googling "AuthenticateAsClient" suggests that it relies on a service point manager which on non-Windows OS may need to be provided by the application.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254738/discussion-between-kol-and-ben-voigt).

Comment: Try doing it `async`. So `using var tcpClient = new TcpClient(); await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ipAddress, tcpPort); using var sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream()); await sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(....` Also the `TargetHost` should be the name from the certificate, but you want to look at the Subject Alternative Name SAN field, not the CN.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks, but async didn't help. I checked the SAN field, it contains 2 IP addresses and 3 DNS names, and I have already tested one of the IP addresses and 1 of the DNS names (the CN is the same as one of them). At the moment it looks like the problem is caused by that AuthenticateAsClient hangs for 30 secs if I use this particular client certificate and private key. I'm trying to track down why.